# What is the opposite of JTable.editCellAt(row,column)?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is there a Java method to cancel the editing of a JTable cell?

I need to get a value from a JTable cell, so if this one is in editing mode, the value getted is a void String.

Comment: See [Table Stop Editing](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JTable.getCellEditor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getCellEditor--)
[`.stopCellEditing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/CellEditor.html#stopCellEditing--)

Note

- that `getCellEditor` returns null if no cell is being edited
- that `stopCellEditing` returns false if stopping of editing failed somehow
- use [`cancelCellEditing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/CellEditor.html#cancelCellEditing--) if you want to cancel the edit, i.e. to not accept any partially edited value